# Nested Linq in MVC4 Razor

Tags: linq, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

currently i'm facing the problem with nested linq.

here is my tables and now i am developing MVC4 Razor web application.

```
student
student_id,studentname,description
book
book_id,student_id,bookname,checkitout
booker
bookerid,book_id,bookername,bookerdescription
```

i create the model for displaying

```
public class student_model{
    public int student_id {get;set;}
    public string studentname {get;set;}
    public string bookname {get;set;}
}
```

Hi all here is my tables and now i am developing MVC4 Razor web application.
i want to write nested LINQ for booker. so i use the following LINQ:

```
public List<student_model> finder (int stuid){
    var stubk = (from stu in contx.students
        join bk in contx.books on stu.student_id equals bk.student_id
        where stu.student_id == stuid
        select new {
            //here is wrong
            student = from bker in contx.bookers
                where bker.book_id=bk.book_id
                select new student_model{
                    student_id = stu.student_id,
                    studentname = stu.studentname,
                    bookname = bk.bookname
                }   
        }).ToList();

    var next = stubk.Select(md=>md.student)

    return (List<student_model>) next;
}
```

It is wrong nested LINQ. so how should i do it to make a filter `bookers.book_id = bk.book_id` ? and how should i return ( `List<student_model` )?

Thanks 
frog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need to use the Bookers class at all for this.

This answer assumes that since you're using Entity Framework, that you have navigation properties on those classes that point to each other (i.e. Books has a property for Student on its class, and Student has a collection of Books on its class).

Using the LINQ extension methods, you can do as follows:

```
var studentModelList = new List<student_model> ();
contx.Students.Include("Books")
              .Where(stu => stu.student_id == stuid)
              .Select(stu => stu.Books).ToList()
              .ForEach(bookObj => 
                      studentModelList.Add(new student_model { student_id = bookObj.student.student_id, studentname = bookObj.student.studentname, bookname = bookObj.bookname}))
return studentModelList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove nesting and add extra join

```
public List<student_model> finder (int stuid){
    var stubk = (from stu in contx.students
        join bk in contx.books on stu.student_id equals bk.student_id
        join bker in contx.bookers on bk.book_id equals bker.book_id
        where stu.student_id == stuid && bker.book_id=bk.book_id
                select new student_model{
                    student_id = stu.student_id,
                    studentname = stu.studentname,
                    bookname = bk.bookname
                }).ToList();
```